# Change The Textview Size Runtime in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

i want to change the textview size runtime dynamically which is used in listview but is not take any effect on textview i divide after getting my screen width in 6 part after getting screen width runtime i am assign the textview size from screen width but this textview is in different layout so how to take this layout in my layout and change the size of textview runtime

here i put my layout

**Home.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/textlayout" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="12"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/flightlist"
                    android:text="Destination"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Flight"

                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/flightlist"
                    android:text="Airlines"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Schedule"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Term Gate"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:background="@drawable/flightlist" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Status"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

             </LinearLayout>

              <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
             >
             </ListView>




</LinearLayout>
```

**list.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textdestination"
        android:layout_width="183dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Destination"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textflight"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Flight"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/flightlist"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textairline"
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Airlines"
        android:textSize="15dp" 
        android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textschedule"
                android:layout_width="73dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Schedule"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/flightlist"
            />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/texttermgate"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Term Gate"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textstatus"
                android:layout_width="73dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Status"
                android:textSize="15dp" 
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/flightlist"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**HomeActivity.java**

```
View inflater=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list2, list, false);
    TextView textdestination=(TextView)inflater.findViewById(R.id.textdestination);
    textdestination.setHeight(50);
    textdestination.setWidth((textlayoutwidth*25)/100);
    textdestination.setTextSize(100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in the `getView()` method of the **Adapter** you use for the ListView.

```
mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent,
                false);
        holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textdestination);
        holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textflight);
        holder.tv3 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textairline);
        .......
        .......
        .......

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if(someCondition){

    holder.tv1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,50));
    holder.tv2setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,50));
    holder.tv3.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,50));
    .....
    .....
    .....
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: BUT I AM USE THIS CODE SO HOW TO DO THIS WITH THIS CODE ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(HomeActivity.this, flightList,
                  R.layout.listportrait,
                  new String[] { TAG_MDESTINATION, TAG_MFLIGHT, TAG_MAIRLINE,TAG_MSCHEDULE,TAG_MTERMINALGATE,TAG_MFSTATUS  }, new int[] {
                    R.id.textdestination, R.id.textflight, R.id.textairline,R.id.textschedule,R.id.texttermgate,R.id.textstatus });
                      
                      setListAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 1):

you can change your textview width and height on runtime with :

```
textdestination.setWidth(pixels);
textdestination.setHeight(pixels);
```

Comment: but you can see this textdestination textview is in another layout so how can we access that layout and thier view

Comment: maybe you should use layout inflater

Comment: this code is not work View inflater=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list2, null);
     TextView textdestination=(TextView)inflater.findViewById(R.id.textdestination);
     textdestination.setHeight(50);
     textdestination.setWidth((textlayoutwidth*25)/100);

Comment: @Mahesh it has not any affect on the size of the textview